# No effect with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css

For the moment, I'm trying to learning some basic jQuery.
But when I try to create a small thing with jQuery, it doesn't work.

First, I thought that it was my standard browser Chrome that was not supported.
When I tried to render it in IE and Firefox, the result stays the same.

What do I wrong ?

Here u can find the code (ps I'm working with a master page, but I don't think that this has any influence)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#orderedlist").addClass("tof");
        $("#orderedlist > li").addClass("groen");
        $("#orderedlist li:last").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("rood");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("rood");
});
    });

</script> </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<ol id="orderedlist">
    <li>Werken met <a href="http://www.jquery.com">JQuery</a></li>
    <li>Gebruik van selectors en events</li>
    <li>Ajax-functionaliteit</li>
</ol>
```

This is CSS (Stijl.css) code:

```
.tof
{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14pt;     
}
.groen 
{
    color:Green;
}

.rood 
{
    color:Red;
}
```

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 9 (example: http://jsfiddle.net/zvvUx/)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'doesn't work'. What extactly does or doesn't work? And have you tried to use FireBug to check for JavaScript errors? Could be as simple as a missing ';' or a wrong path to jquery.js.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's error console for any errors? Since the code seems to work for mVChr, why don't you check the jquery path that you have provided to ensure that the file is indeed present. Alternatively you can use a CDN for starters. <script  type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Comment: the problem has to do with master page, just tried with a single empty aspx page (that works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/M2ev9/1/).

It seems like your code is working as intended. So try upgrading to jQuery 1.4.4. The only difference is that this doesn't use  tags.

I reckon your issue is that your generated HTML from the asp is not the same as your aspx files.

To be safe you can use the selecter `$("[id$=orderedlist]")` which will work even if .NET prepends your id with junk.

Comment: it is not working with this selecter. I made an single empty aspx page (no from master page) and now it is working.

Comment: @Thomas try it with `$=` or `-=` and don't copy over my `L` in your id.

Answer (score 2):

I see no obvious errors in your code.

I believe it might be a Dollar-sign conflict with any other library, like MooTools or Prototype.

Try to wrap your script with an anonymous function like this:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#orderedlist").addClass("tof");
    $("#orderedlist > li").addClass("groen");
    $("#orderedlist li:last").hover(
    function () {
       $(this).addClass("rood");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("rood");
    });
  });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

If there is another library causing a Dollar-sign conflict this should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for noting possible $ conflict. But please do use `jQuery.noConflict`

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please motivate .noConflict() in this particular situation?

Comment: noConflict is used to remove jQuery's $ alias from global scope. I just think it's nice to use so that your certain the original `$` does what you think it does. Or at least mention it.

Comment: +1. I began to write an answer myself, but I suspected that you would write it better for documentation purposes. I was right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The master page does make a difference and most likely the reason for your issue. The master page will render your html markup with a different ID than the one you specified.
so for example, this would render something like:

```
<ol id="Content2_Control1_orderedlist">
    <li>Werken met <a href="http://www.jquery.com">JQuery</a></li>
    <li>Gebruik van selectors en events</li>
    <li>Ajax-functionaliteit</li>
</ol>
```

so therefore the jquery selectors using the ID will not work properly.

Comment: This is only true if the `ol` has a `runat="server"` attribute, which it doesn't in this example.

Comment: i used a single aspx page without master page, and now it is working.